# Android - super always gets called last?

Tags: android, overriding

To handle orientation changes, im overriding:

```
onConfigurationChanged
```

But regardless of where I make the call to

```
super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
```

The super always gets executed AFTER my code

Is it possible to have code be executed after the super, which is after its rotated?

Edit:  I guess there's no way around this.  It seems that when you override a function, the super gets executed last no matter what.

Comment: onConfigurationChanged is called back... AFTER CONFIGURATION CHANGED
that is, the orientation change has already occurred ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a break point on your super.onConfiguratioNChanged, I highly doubt that "regardless of where [you] put the call" it still calls it last.

Comment: If I call super first, then call my function, and put a breakpoint on my function, super never gets executed (screen never rotates)

Comment: You're right, I was wrong about the order of some stuff that was getting called behind the scenes